# java algorithm for search with different increment number

Tags: java, algorithm, oop

I have next data:
[image: data]

need create algorithm on java whet will return result dependent on input value
for example:

1. any value from 1 to 7 must return 0
2. from 38 to 52 return 3
3. if input will be 40 that resul 3
4. ......

   I do not know the data in advance, I know only algorithm in witch they populating

I have started with next code:

```
 public int getAmountOfUnits(int duration ) {
if (duration >= 1 && duration <= 7) return 0;
if (duration >= 8 && duration <= 82) {}
return 1;
```

}

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It is not a question about an issue, but an assignment you ask.  Anyway, you write the logic in english, just translate it in java and you have your answer

Comment: '40' should return '3', right? By the way, if there's no mathematical correlation in that sequence, there's no real "algorithm" that you can use. You are forced to maintain a structure with those mappings, and return the correct value by checking that.

Comment: yes, but need help to translate it in java

Comment: "'40' should return '3', right?" yes, mistake, I will fix

Comment: Sorry to say this, but I speak in the name of the site: these requests are not intended for SO. You should have some code to share at least, in order that the community could address the issue with more precision. The community won't write code from scratch.

Comment: `if input <= 7 return 0; if input <= 22 return 1; if input <= ...` and so on. Starting with `91`, use a loop to check further intervals. Or put the upper-bounds in an array and binary-search the index in that array.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what information you have as input? Maybe the first ` begin`  value and the increments array?

Comment: on input I have only any random number,  and need find result regarding begin and end range

Comment: This is obviously an impossible task if you don't actually know the ranges.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `Arrays.binarySearch`,

```
static int indexInRanges(int[] rangeEndPoints, int value) {
    int bsPos = Arrays.binarySearch(rangeEndPoints, value);
    if (bsPos < 0)
        return ~bsPos;
    else
        return bsPos;
}

// test code
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    int[] rangeEndPoints = { 7, 22, 37, 52, 67, 82, 90, 114, 138, 162, 186, 210, 234, 258, 282, 306, 330, 354 };
    System.out.println("1 -> " + indexInRanges(rangeEndPoints, 1));
    System.out.println("40 -> " + indexInRanges(rangeEndPoints, 40));
    System.out.println("350 -> " + indexInRanges(rangeEndPoints, 350));
}
```

This code does not attempt to handle more general cases, such as:

- other output values than simply the index (but you can use an extra array for that)
- gaps in the list of ranges
- input values not contained in any range

Alternatively you can write that `if < 0` etc thing as `return bsPos ^ (bsPos >> 31)` at the cost of making it less obvious what it does.

As a special case, since most of your ranges are the same size, you could hack something together with only a few `if/else` cases and some divisions, but that hard-codes the list of ranges in a particularly hard-to-change way.

Comment: thx for help, but I cant create int[] rangeEndPoints ={} I dont know I do not know the data in advance

Comment: I know only algorithm in wich they populating

Comment: @Orion you can make that array when you get the data then

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways for doing that task.This is the one of simple algorithm.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class search{
  public static void main(String a[]){

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter  Value :");
    int value=sc.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter increment value :");
    int increment=sc.nextInt();

    int i;
    int counter=0;int c=0;

    int[] result={1,8,23,38,53,68,83,91,115,139,163,187,211,235,259,283,307,331};

    for(i=0;i<result.length;i++){
        counter++;
        if(value<=(result[i]+increment)){
            System.out.print("result is :" + (counter-1));
            counter=0;
            c++;
            break;
        }
    }   
    if(c==0){
        System.out.print("Not found!");
     }  

  }
```

}

Comment: looks good, but as I said I dont have this date {1,8,23,38,53,68,83,91,115,139,163,187,211,235,259,283,307,331}
it can be {1,8,23,38,53,68,83,91,115,139,163,187,211,235,259,283,307,331,........................}
I know only that numbers after number  114 increments on 23

And I dont know how many them will be

Comment: array result cannot have fixed size